# Surface pro 3 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux-headers

Hey guys I have successfully install Ubuntu on my device using rEFInd and updated the kernel to 4.16.2 
Everything is working but the WIFI doesn't work correctly.. If I open my device after suspend it changes from the WIFI logo to the Ethernet logo and then it disconnects and says "Activation failed" and err (24)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You should remove kernel `4.16.2` and use the normal supported kernel instead. Only if there is a problem with the normal kernel would you install the most recent. That said I use `4.14.34` an LTS kernel for 6 years rather than 4.15 or 4.16 which have a short life span of a couple months.

Answer (score 0):

The wifi on my machine was very bad and laggy so i use a samsung wireless lan adapter from 2009 that i have lying around. I would suggest using a wireless lan adapter and plug it into your usb port.